# set/add view from controller action

Tags: zend-framework, view, controller

I'm trying to set a view script to be executed in addition to the currently requested action view script. I want to do this from the controller action itself in a way that this new view script output will be available from the layout $this->layout()->content helper.

I found the setView() method but don't know how to use it from the controller.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want to output second script INSEATD of another or concatinate both of them?

Comment: If one could show me the 2 approaches (replace or concatenate) then that would be perfet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to render some other view script from a controller just:

```
$this->render('someotherview');
```

Wich will render someotherview.phtml.
from: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.viewintegration.render

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
public function fooAction()
{
    // Renders my/foo.phtml
    $this->render();

    // Renders my/bar.phtml
    $this->render('bar');

    // Renders baz.phtml
    $this->render('baz', null, true);

    // Renders my/login.phtml to the 'form' segment of the
    // response object
    $this->render('login', 'form');

    // Renders site.phtml to the 'page' segment of the response
    // object; does not use the 'my/' subirectory
    $this->render('site', 'page', true);
}

public function bazBatAction()
{
    // Renders my/baz-bat.phtml
    $this->render();
}
```

}

Should get you on the right track!

Also

```
$this->renderScript('path/to/index.phtml');
```

Works really well.